# :update form is not saving boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean

I'm a beginner building an app for my language students that checks whether the user copied a term correctly into a form. The Word model has a :term attribute, which is what the user will be copying. The Word Exposition model is associated with the Word model; upon enrollment each WordExposition-Word association's :completed attribute is set to false. I'm trying to implement a form in the WordExposition show view, such that if the user types the correct term, the WordExposition completed attribute will change to true from the default false.

In order to check whether the Word.term matches the term that the student copied I have a `word_from_student_matches_word` method in the WordExposition model, which I want to run before updating. As of now, I'm getting `undefined local variable or method`word_from_student_matches_word'` upon submission of the form.  How could I go about checking for matching spelling and updating the boolean attribute from the view?

WordExposition model:

```
class WordExposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enrollment
  belongs_to :word

  delegate :term, to: :word 
  delegate :reference, to: :word
  delegate :image, to: :word
  delegate :sound, to: :word

  attr_accessor :term_given_by_student
  validate :word_from_student_matches_word, on: :update

  def word_from_student_matches_word
    return true if word.term == term_given_by_student
    errors.add(:term_given_by_student, "Terms don't match")
  end

  def next_word_exposition
    WordExposition.where(["id > ? AND lesson_id = ?", id, lesson_id]).first
  end
end
```

Word Expositions controller:

```
class WordExpositionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :require_enrollment_in_lesson

  def show
    @word = current_enrollment.word_expositions.find_by!(word_id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    current_word_exposition 
    if word_from_student_matches_word
      current_word_exposition.completed = true
      current_word_exposition.save
    end
  end

  private

  helper_method :current_lesson
  def current_lesson
    @current_lesson ||= Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
  end

  helper_method :current_enrollment
  def current_enrollment
    @current_enrollment ||= Enrollment.find_by!(lesson_id: params[:lesson_id], user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def require_enrollment_in_lesson
    if !(current_user.enrolled_in?(current_lesson))
      redirect_to lesson_path(current_lesson), alert: 'You need to enroll in order to view the activities!'
    end
  end

  def word_exposition_params
    params.require(:word_exposition).permit(:completed)
  end

  def current_word_exposition
    @current_word_exposition ||= WordExposition.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Word Expositions show view:

```
<h1>Word Exposition</h1>

<!-- display the term to be copied -->
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
  <h2><%= @word.term %></h2><br>

  <!-- Form to check matching spelling and update WordExposition :completed to true if correct -->
  <%= simple_form_for @word, url: lesson_word_exposition_path(current_lesson, @word), method: :patch do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :term_given_by_student, label: "Enter the term exactly as above:" %><br>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Rake routes:

```
      lesson_enrollments POST   /lessons/:lesson_id/enrollments(.:format)            enrollments#create
  lesson_word_exposition GET    /lessons/:lesson_id/word_expositions/:id(.:format)   word_expositions#show
                         PATCH  /lessons/:lesson_id/word_expositions/:id(.:format)   word_expositions#update
                         PUT    /lessons/:lesson_id/word_expositions/:id(.:format)   word_expositions#update
                 lessons GET    /lessons(.:format)                                   lessons#index
                  lesson GET    /lessons/:id(.:format)                               lessons#show
                    word GET    /words/:id(.:format)                                 words#show
    teacher_lesson_words POST   /teacher/lessons/:lesson_id/words(.:format)          teacher/words#create
 new_teacher_lesson_word GET    /teacher/lessons/:lesson_id/words/new(.:format)      teacher/words#new
edit_teacher_lesson_word GET    /teacher/lessons/:lesson_id/words/:id/edit(.:format) teacher/words#edit
     teacher_lesson_word PATCH  /teacher/lessons/:lesson_id/words/:id(.:format)      teacher/words#update
                         PUT    /teacher/lessons/:lesson_id/words/:id(.:format)      teacher/words#update
                         DELETE /teacher/lessons/:lesson_id/words/:id(.:format)      teacher/words#destroy
         teacher_lessons POST   /teacher/lessons(.:format)                           teacher/lessons#create
      new_teacher_lesson GET    /teacher/lessons/new(.:format)                       teacher/lessons#new
     edit_teacher_lesson GET    /teacher/lessons/:id/edit(.:format)                  teacher/lessons#edit
          teacher_lesson GET    /teacher/lessons/:id(.:format)                       teacher/lessons#show
                         PATCH  /teacher/lessons/:id(.:format)                       teacher/lessons#update
                         PUT    /teacher/lessons/:id(.:format)                       teacher/lessons#update
                         DELETE /teacher/lessons/:id(.:format)                       teacher/lessons#destroy
```

Comment: In your controller you call `word_from_student_matches_word` but that method is defined on the model instance.

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong in your controller

```
def update
  current_word_exposition
  current_word_exposition.completed = true #this line move to callback in your model changing the flag before save
  if current_word_exposition.save
    #nothing o something
  else
    #do something
  end
end
```

Your model is validating the term on update, and return false if something went wrong. Just need to save the model instance and control the result

Comment: I added an else alert, which is showing even if the terms match. This means that the validation is not running, and the update is not saving. Any ideas as to how to solve this? Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Because  you are not filling the new value to  model instance, current_word_exposition.term = params[:word][:term] or current_word_exposition.update(params) and your word_exposition_params method is wrong also, it must permit :term_given_by_student and not :completed

Comment: Does that still apply if my WordExposition model holds only a :completed boolean parameter? I don't want to pass the word that is in the form, just to update it to true if the terms match.